# Solving a simple Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a simple Ricatti equation and am not sure i'm correct. Since this is probably the simplest common case I thought I'd post it here:

Write the Riccati equation as
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d E (\tau) }{d \tau} =  e_2 E(\tau)^2 + e_1 E(\tau) + e_0
\end{equation*}
where 
we can reduce to a second order linear equation via the substitution $E(\tau) = - \frac{1}{e_2} \frac{w^\prime (\tau)}{w(\tau)}$ which yields
\begin{equation*}
w^{\prime \prime} - e_1 w^\prime + e_2 e_0 w = 0.
\end{equation*}
The general solution to this ODE is $w(\tau) = C_{1} e^{r_{1} \tau} + C_{2} e^{r_{2} \tau}$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the positive and negative roots
\begin{align*}
r_{1,2} = \frac{e_1 \pm \sqrt{e_1^2 - 4 e_2 e_0}}{2} = \frac{e_1 \pm q}{2}  
\end{align*}
and $C_{1,2}$ are constants determined by the boundary condition. A general solution for $E(\tau)$ is then
\begin{align*}
E(\tau) &= - \frac{1}{e_2} \frac{C_1 r_{1} e^{r_{1} \tau} + C_2 r_{2} e^{r_{2} \tau}}{C_1 e^{r_{1} \tau} + C_2 e^{r_{2} \tau}}
=  - \frac{1}{e_2} \frac{C r_{1} e^{r_{1} \tau} + r_{2} e^{r_{2} \tau}}{C e^{r_{1} \tau} + e^{r_{2} \tau}}  
\end{align*}

Does this look correct? How else can these ODEs be solved?

Comment: Am I missing the question?

Comment: yes - sorry! edited.

Comment: If your $e_0,\,e_1,\,e_2$ are constants, then you equation is separable and can be integrated directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your non linear OE $$\frac{d E (\tau) }{d \tau} =  e_2 E(\tau)^2 + e_1 E(\tau) + e_0
$$ is rewritten as $$\frac{d E }{d x} =  R(x) E^2 + Q(x)E + P(x),~~~(*)$$ just for the simplicity in indexes and the variable $\tau$ is our usual variable $x$. Another method in which you can overcome the OE would be to use a *known* particular solution of $(*)$, say $y_1$. Then set $y=y_1+u$ wherein $u$ is a solution of $$\frac{du}{dx}-(Q+2y_1R)u=Ru^2$$ Since the latter OE is a *Bernoulli equation* with $n=2$, it can be turned into a linear OE: $$\frac{dw}{dx}+(Q+2y_1R)w=-R$$ where $w=u^{1-2}=u^{-1}$.

Comment: @flashdesign2550: Thanks. :) but let us to be seen by the OP.

Comment: Thanks. So three methods:
(1) Direct integration
(2) Reduction to second order linear ODE
(3) Reduction to Bernoulli equation